# Minimize Variance of a random variable $(X = X_1 + X_2)$.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

I'm attempting a problem here that I'm sure I know the solution to, but I can't come to the solution without some amount of pure intuition.

Suppose I have a random variable which describes a measurement made by a tool $X_1$ and another made by another tool $X_2$. These are independent, and happen to have the same expected values,

i.e.

$$ E(X_1) = \mu = E(X_2) $$

But not necessarily the same variance. Now suppose I estimate $\mu$ by taking the weighted average of two measurements

$$ \bar{\mu} = wX_1 + (1-w)X_2 $$

I've figured, using properties of the expected value on independent variables, that the expected value of $\bar{\mu}$ is actually just $\mu$.

$$ E(\bar{\mu}) = E(wX_1 + (1-w)X_2) = wE(X_1) + (1-x)E(X_2) = w\mu + (1-w)\mu = \mu $$

But now I'm interested in finding $w$ such that I minimize the variance in  $\bar{\mu}$. Intuitively, I would want to choose the weighting factor to be either 0 or 1 so that I omit the variance in one of my random variables ... I don't want to add the variance in one random variable to the variance in the other; I'm always better off taking the fewest number of measurements because the variance is associated with *each* measure.

How do I show this?

$$ V(X_1 + X_2) = V(X_1) + V(X_2) = \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 $$

What should I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$V(wX_1+(1-w)X_2) = w^2 \sigma_1^2 + (1-w)^2 \sigma_2^2.$$
The derivative (with respect to $w$) is $2w\sigma_1^2 - 2(1-w)\sigma_2^2$, and the second derivative is $2(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)\ge 0$, so the variance is convex in $w$. Setting the derivative equal to zero shows that the variance is minimized at $w=\frac{\sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}$ with value $\frac{\sigma_1^2 \sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}$. Setting $w=0$ or $w=1$ actually yields a local maximum for the variance, since in those cases the variances are $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$ respectively.

---

Example: suppose $\sigma_1^2=4$ and $\sigma_2^2=1$. Then $w=0$ gives a variance of $4$, while $w=1$ gives a variance of $1$. However, $w=\frac{1}{5}$ gives a variance of $\frac{4}{25}+\frac{16}{25} = \frac{4}{5}$.